# Usage of page factory class in magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, template, factory

What is the purpose of rendering the custom module page in Magento2 using the result factory `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory` class injected in the constructor and making the page to display

```
$resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
```

rather than doing these below kind of display which is same like in Magento 1.x approach

```
$this->_view->loadLayout();

$this->_view->renderLayout();
```

Answer (score 16):

Actually is not necessary to return an instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page`. The `execute` is expected to return an instance of a class that implements the interface `\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface`.

`\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page` is just one possible return.
Other possible returns are

- `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect`
- `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw`
- `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout`
- `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward`
- `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json`

and there may be others.
take a look at the method `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::dispatch()`.
This should return an instance of `\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface` and based on the result different actions are taken, again by calling methods declared in the `ResultInterface`.
This `dispatch` method calls `$result = $this->execute();` which is the `execute` method from the controller action. 
So I guess this is for consistency and to make it easier to introduce a different behavior for a controller action. You just need to add a new class that implements `ResultInterface` and it will all be handled by the framework.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that idea was return data/models from controllers, but current implementation looks strange for me too.

Personally I expect to that controllers do not return anything, maybe just redirect to other url. To page layout need adds route on with this page will be available.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login">
     <route url="login"/>
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

JSON will available from rest api